# Adding consul to the existing AWS HashiCorp Vault deployment guide

Tags: amazon-web-services, consul, hashicorp-vault

I used the [AWS HashiCorp Vault deployment guide](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/vault/) which was very straight forward and useful. However, this uses the raft storage as a backend and I need to use consul for some of our own updated requirements. What is the best approach to adding consul to this existing deployment or should I redeploy from scratch?

Comment: Or I'm looking for a walkthrough guide on deploying vault and consul to AWS on EC2 or EKS, either would work fine just so long as it's highly available.

Comment: there is this guide that mentions the consul -> raft migration. My guess is that you can just follow it on the reverse https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/commands/operator/migrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that? From Hashicorp :

https://www.hashicorp.com/resources/deploy-a-production-ready-vault-cluster-on-aws-in-5-minutes

Comment: exactly that, not sure how that one escaped my searches but thanks!